# ngIf condition not evaluating in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ng-if

I am trying to display an error in reactive form using ngIf by evaluating an expression inside it!
if anyone has any idea why it isn't working?

**Template Div**

```
<div *ngIf="submitted && question.required && f(question.slug).errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <p>hello</p>
      <div *ngIf="f(question.slug).errors.required">*this field is required</div>
</div>
```

**.ts function**

```
f(slug){
    return this.question_form.controls[`${slug}`]
}
```

I have verified that the f function is returning some object and the conditions in ngIf i.e. *submitted and question.required* results in true but in ngIf the condition isn't resulting to true.

Comment: Try removing `class="invalid-feedback"` and see if error displays

Comment: @OwenKelvin yes it works! if you can tell me why this works?

Comment: Its something to do with that class `invalid-feedback` and the neighboring input. For that class to display the input has to have an invalid status. e.g in your case the input must be returning a valid status hence css does not display